# Events that points to a function that takes arguments

Tags: c#, function, events, delegates, arguments

Every function in C# that can be used for an event has only object sender and eventargs e as arguments. My question is if there's a way to pass this limitation? thank you.

Comment: "is there a way to pass this limitation?" Yes.  Please provide more detail on what you want to do for a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Every function in C# that can be used for an event has only object sender and eventargs e as arguments. My question is if there's a way to pass this limitation? thank you.

The most common way to handle this is to use a closure with a lambda:

```
// Suppose you want to have access to these variables
int data = 42; 
double arg = 5948.2903;

foo.SomeEvent += (s,e) =>
{
     Console.WriteLine("data == {0}, arg == {1}", data, arg); // You can use those here
};
```

That being said, if you're *creating* the event as well as subscribing to it, you can use a custom `EventArgs` type (or even break convention and make the event any delegate type you choose).  You can also create a custom class to handle the event, and pass data into it (which is effectively what the closure/lambda approach above does).

Comment: what is this => you used? I've never seen it.

Comment: @user3050072 It's a lambda expression: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 0):

events don't *necessarily* need to follow that pattern.  You can easily create your own events using whatever signature that you want.  Here's how you can declare an event that provides no parameters:

```
public event Action SomeEvent;
```

It is merely a convention that is commonly followed for events to pass in the sender and an `EventArgs` object.  It is in no way a requirement of the language.

However, you can only change the signature of events for your own types, you can't go around changing the signature of events in classes you don't control.  Here there isn't a choice; the handler *must* match the signature of the event for you to be able to attach it.  If you want to call a method with another signature your only option is to create a handler with the proper signature that calls out to a method with another signature.  You can simplify the amount of code needed to do this, as Reed mentions in his answer, by using a lambda:

```
SomeOtherEvent += (sender, args) => SomeMethod(localVariableToCloseOver);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own eventargs class that inherits eventargs and supply whatever data you'll need.

Comment: Not if you don't control the definition of the class that defines the method you can't.  And if you *do* control the definition, you aren't even bound by the use of `EventArgs` in the first place; you can supply your own signature entirely.

Answer (score 0):

> Every function in C# that can be used for an event has only `object sender` and `eventargs e` as arguments

This is not true - every event *that requires an `EventHandler` delagate* has those arguments.  Different events have different event handler types.

`Control.Click`, for example only requires an EventHandler because the only relevany information needed for a generic click event is *what* was clicked (`sender`).

`MouseClick`, on the other hand, passes a `MoiuseEventArgs` which includes other information specific to that event, such as what button was clicked, the coordinates, what type of click (single or double click), etc.)

So if you need more information in your event, the easiest way to do that is to inherit from `EventArgs` and use that type as a generic parameter to `EventHandler<T>`:

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
   public string MyEventData {get; set;}
}

public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;
```

You can then provide either a delegate or a lambda to handle the event.

```
MyEvent += (s, me) => me.MyEventData = "foo";
```